For $C^*$-algebras A and B is the map $A\times B \to A\otimes_{\min} B$ continuous?
For $C^*$-algebras A and B is the map $A\times B \to A\otimes_{\min} B$ continuous? Where $A\times B$ has product topology and $A\otimes_{\min} B$ the norm topology. If yes, a proof (or reference) would be great!
For completeness, let $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ be faithful representations of $A$ and $B$, respectively. Then $A\otimes_{\min} B$ is the closure of the algebraic tensor product under the norm $\|\sum a\odot b\| = \|\sum \pi_1(a)\odot \pi_2(b)\|$ (and the sums are finite).
I have a hard time figuring out the inverse image of an open set in $A\otimes_{\min} B$.

It’s a bilinear map. A bilinear map is continuous iff it is bounded. And $|a \otimes b| = |a||b|$, so the map is bounded. (This holds not just for the min norm, but for any $C^\ast$ norm on the algebraic tensor product.)
